Trying to figure out how to put up last row of siding
My friend helped me build my garden shed.  Basically he knew what he was doing and did most of the work and I was the gopher or helping hold things in place etc.  So we are basically done now with a few finishing touches left.  My question is about the siding.  On one side of the shed, he is unsure about how to put up the last row of siding.  He said that if we had an inch less height or an inch more height it would work.  But its a weird height left for that last row.  I know we'll have to cut some height off the last piece.  But how do we stick it in place without being able to nail the top?  Also, this type of siding is 2 rows in one, if that makes sense, not sure what that is called.  I have included 2 pictures to show details of what the shed looks like.



I think it is cut to size to fit and nails place at the top.  Then the top piece on there already is placed on to hide the nails/top of the last piece.  Usually place the siding first then the soffits(dark pieces)

Yeah, I think you're gonna have to basically "rip" a row of siding to fit, and basically jam it under the J-channel at the top.  You might be able to get some nails into it at an angle, but I'd think if cut properly the J-channel should retain it sufficiently.  With the J-channel overhanging it, it should be adequately weatherproof.
